# Updating ProgressBar using Service through out all the Activities

Tags: android, multithreading, service, progress-bar, intentservice

I have an application in which as per the requirements, images are being downloaded from the background thread processing. As per the needs, I want to show the horizontal progress bar on all the activities, while photos are being downloaded. Also this is the class which is responsible for whole Json parsing of my application.
For that I implemented a class which extends Service and called its onCreate method. But I am still not clear about how do I update the progress bar in the current and also if the user switches on other screen, the progress bar should update accordingly.
Previously I tried using the IntentService class, but it requires

```
MyService (String name){
  super(name);
}
```

But unfortunately its not fitting in my situation and I stuck getting the logcat exception like `'cant instantiate the default constructor of IntentService'`

I am really stuck at this situation. Please suggest me some way/ code snippet if this situation has been faced by anyone out there.

Here is my current sample code : http://pastebin.com/HCWFPtbb

Comment: Wrong approach for downloading the images you are using Service .. please try to use AsyncTask class .

Comment: AsyncTask is useful only if I remain on first screen only and can show the progress accordingly. But what if the user navigates to other screen while downloading is still continued in the background? How can you notify the second activity about this downloading progress??

Comment: Use Thread with separate handler and post runnable .. as it is not tied with any activity or other component You can ask it globally in your application . Services use is something different . Even if you use services IntentService , It will only perform the tasks in a queue , It will not create the MultiThreading environment .

Comment: I used handler and thread earlier. It fits for the situation when you are posting your UI response to your handler on a single screen. How will you send message from Runnable to your multiple activities and how will you notify the same thing in background?

Comment: If you look internally into the code of AsyncTask class , It uses thread pool which is more efficiently implemneted than creating threads and running it . For more details please look into the ThreadpoolExecuter implementation .

Comment: Like suppose if you have four screens and four instances of a class extending thread and new handler object . So when your activity will come into the onResume can check the status form thread itself or Class Extending thread can notify the activity component even for single runnbale completion .

Comment: My class solely not downloads images but also responsible for doing whole Json parsing for my app. Earlier I tried using AsyncTask and its running well for the first screen without problem. But then if user switches to other screens, the progress should continue on incrementing untill the photos are downloaded

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16254/discussion-between-yudroid-and-deepak-sharma)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public final class DownloadThread extends Thread
    {

        private static final String       TAG           = DownloadThread.class.getSimpleName();

        private Handler                   handler;

        private int                       totalQueued;

        private int                       totalCompleted;

        private final DownloadThreadListener listener;

        private boolean                   isRunning   = false;

        protected boolean                   isStop;

        private TaskInitiator               mtaskInitiator = null;

        /**
         * @return the isRunning
         */
        public boolean isRunning()
            {
                return isRunning;
            }

        public DownloadThread(DownloadThreadListener listener)
            {
                this.listener = listener;
                isStop = false;
            }

        @Override
        public void run()
            {
                try
                    {

                        Looper.prepare();

                        mtaskInitiator = new TaskInitiator();
                        handler = new Handler();
                        isRunning = true;

                        Looper.loop();

                    }
                catch (Throwable t)
                    {
                        Log.e(TAG, "DownloadThread halted due to an error", t);
                    }
            }

        public synchronized void requestStop()
            {

                isStop = true;

            }

        public synchronized void enqueueDownload(DownloadTask task)
            {

                mtaskInitiator = new TaskInitiator();
                mtaskInitiator.setTask(task);
                handler.post(mtaskInitiator);
                totalQueued++;

            }

        public synchronized void removeTasks()
            {

                if (mtaskInitiator != null)
                    {

                        handler.removeCallbacks(mtaskInitiator);
                        totalQueued = 0;
                        totalCompleted = 0;
                    }
            }

        class TaskInitiator implements Runnable
            {

                private DownloadTask task = null;

                public DownloadTask getTask()
                    {
                        return task;
                    }

                public void setTask(DownloadTask task)
                    {
                        this.task = task;
                    }

                public TaskInitiator()
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                    }

                @Override
                public void run()
                    {
                        try
                            {
                                task.run();

                            }
                        finally
                            {

                                if (isStop)
                                    {
                                        Looper.myLooper().quit();
                                    }
                                synchronized (DownloadThread.this)
                                    {
                                        signalUpdate(task.getCurrentBitmap(), task.getCurrentFeedUrl());
                                        task.setCurrentBitmap(null);
                                        totalCompleted++;

                                    }

                            }

                    }

            }

        public synchronized int getTotalQueued()
            {
                return totalQueued;
            }

        public synchronized int getTotalCompleted()
            {
                return totalCompleted;
            }

        public void signalUpdate(Bitmap bmap, String bmapUrl)
            {

                if (listener != null)
                    {
                        listener.handleDownloadThreadUpdate(bmap, bmapUrl);
                    }
            }

    }
```

And let your Activity component implement the below interface for callback from Thread class.

```
public interface DownloadThreadListener {

void handleDownloadThreadUpdate(Bitmap bmap,String bmapUrl);

Map<String, Bitmap> giveImages_Map();

ConcurrentHashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> giveSoftImages_Map();
```

}

Comment: Accepting yours answer as it gave me some direction to think this way. But I solved my problem rather in a very different way using thread and calling method on each screen individually.